# Type traits for both `type` and `const type`

Tags: c++, templates

I'm in a need for some sort of a type trait:

```
template<typename T> struct foo {};
template<>
struct foo<char> { static constexpr char c = 'c' };
```

This works perfectly if I need a character `c` of the type `char`, but doesn't in the following case:

```
printf("%c", foo<const char>::c);
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this, rather than specify the template for both `char` and `const char` in the same way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a partial specialization:

```
template <class T> struct foo<const T> : foo<T> {};
```

Answer (score 3):

Apart from T.C.'s correct answer, if you need this kind of construct a lot, you can use the following. I don't know if it is a idiom, but I find it very useful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename>
class TraitImpl;

template <typename T>
using Trait = TraitImpl<std::remove_const_t<T>>;

template <>
class TraitImpl<char>
{
    public:
    static constexpr char value = 'c';
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Trait<char>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << Trait<const char>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Basically you define `Trait` as an alias to `TraitImpl`, but with the template argument of `TraitImpl` being a modified type of `Trait`'s template parameter. If you also need `volatile char` etc to use the same implementation of the trait class, you can replace `remove_const` with `remove_cv`. The same goes to if you need signed or unsigned integers to use the same trait class. There are a lot possibility of this kind of use of alias. If you are limited to C++11, replace `remove_const_t<T>` to `typename remove_const<T>::type`. If you are limited to C++98, replace the type alias to a public inheritance and use Boost type traits or write your own, which is easy in these simple cases.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do that is by using partial specialization and a second template parameter with a default value.
It is somehow more flexible than the other solutions, for you can easily use the other traits from `type_traits` to tune the accepted types.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>

template<typename T, typename U = std::remove_const_t<T>>
struct S;

template<typename T>
struct S<T, char> { static constexpr char c = 'c'; };

int main() {
    static_assert(S<const char>::c == 'c', "!");
    static_assert(S<char>::c == 'c', "!");
}
```

As you can note, it doesn't require to add an extra specialization for `const` or whatever.
The basic idea is to use the one you are already defining.

As a side note, if you want to extend the proposed solution to all the other types, you can simply use this specialization instead of the one above:

```
template<typename T>
struct S<T> {
    // ...
};
```

It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>

template<typename T, typename U = std::decay_t<T>>
struct S;

template<typename T>
struct S<T> { static constexpr char c = 'c'; };

struct U {};

int main() {
    static_assert(S<const U &>::c == 'c', "!");
    static_assert(S<U>::c == 'c', "!");
}
```